# Joomla module form to submit to same page

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla module in an article.  The module has a form, and when I submit the form I want it to reload the same page (and some PHP will take care of the form's new state).

Is there any way to do this with a module, without using ajax?  Because at the moment Joomla throws a 404 and I can't figure out where the form is trying to submit to.

Let's say my page is `http://www.example.com/payment`

The form submits to `http://www.example.com/404`

This is my form:

```
<form method="post">
    <label>Order ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $_POST['id']; ?>" />
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Continue" />
</form>
```

I have tried having no form action, as well as:

```
action="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=8"

action="/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=8"

action="payment"

action="/payment"
```

It always submits to 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be with submiting `id` via `input`, because Joomla uses `id` internally to find the correct route, so if you overwrite it with your request, Joomla will try to get article/category with unexisting `id`.

So, try to rename the name of the input with id and see what happens.